# Login is not working php oracle

Tags: php, oracle

when I try to log in, it just does not work, the code should enter the if and write a message "Adelante!" but it does not work (enter the else) I searched the error for a long time but I can not find it. I made sure that the data is good, and try with more tables from the Schema DB but nothing works either ... No error or anything indicates the console either

Here is the code

**Page 1:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sistema de login</title>
    <style type="text/css">

        h1{
            text-align: center;
        }

        table{
            width: 25%;
            background-color: #FFC;
            border: 2px dotted #F00;
            margin: auto; 
        }

        .izq{
            text-align: right;
        }
        .der{
            text-align: left;
        }
        td{
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1> INRODUCE TUS DATOS</h1>

<form action = "59sistema_login2.php" method="post"> 
<table>
    <tr><td class="izq">Login:</td><td class="der"><input type="text" name="login"></td></tr><tr><td class="izq">Password:</td><td class ="der"><input type="password" name="password"></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="enviar" value="LOGIN"></td></tr> 
<table>

</body>
</html>
```

**Page 2: (59sistema_login2.php)**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    try
    {
        $base = new PDO('oci:dbname=localhost', 'hr','hr');
        $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql= "SELECT * FROM DEPARTMENTS WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID=:login AND MANAGER_ID=:password";
        $resultado = $base->prepare($sql);
        $login = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["login"])); 
        $password = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["password"]));
        $resultado->bindValue(":login", $login); 
        $resultado->bindValue(":password", $password);

        $resultado->execute();

        $numero_registro=$resultado->rowCount(); 

        echo "valor: $numero_registro<br><br>";
        echo "$login con $password";

        if($numero_registro!=0) //el usuario existe
        {
            echo "<h2>Adelante!!</h2>";

        }
        else 
        {
            header("location:59sistema_login.php"); //redirigo a la pag login
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        die("Error: " .$e->getMessage());
    }


?>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**UPDATE**

I create a new file and tried putting this and I print the CONNECTION OK, that means that the connection would be fine (?)

```
<?php
    try
    { 
         $base = new PDO('oci:dbname=localhost', 'hr','hr'); 
        echo "Conexión OK!";
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        die('Error: ' .$e->GetMessage());
    }

    finally
    {
        $base = null; //vacio la memoria
    }
?>
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

I executed this line of code to see if the drivers are installed correctly.

```
<?php foreach(PDO::getAvailableDrivers() as $driver)
    echo $driver, '\n';
?>
```

It shows: mysql\noci\nsqlite\n

Comment: Have you tried putting wrong password and correct password? Maybe you are confused to this part if($numero_registro!=0).

Comment: I changed the select for an insert and there if the message "Adelante!" appears and the echoes are the following ones: el 1,7777 con 200, object (PDO) # 1 (0) {}, Adelante!!
but when I do a select it shows 0 in the number of affected rows, it seems that the problem is rowCount: S I do not know why it does not work.

Comment: Are you sure the password is in the `MANAGER_ID` field?

Comment: yes, i did. the problem is rowcount

Comment: This is really a duplicate of your other post I answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47741778/general-error-1008-ocistmtexecute-ora-01008-not-all-variables-bound

Comment: Possible duplicate of [General error: 1008 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-01008: not all variables bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47741778/general-error-1008-ocistmtexecute-ora-01008-not-all-variables-bound)